# Who are the people on meta stackoverflow? :)

Tags: discussion, meta

What's the main personality type?
How much are they all experts in a specific stack-related domain?
To what varying degrees are they affiliated with the official company behind StackExchange sites, if at all?

Just (very) curious...

Comment: Hi Matt, all (basically) answerable questions, but I'm wondering what you're trying to learn by asking this that you can't get from a cursory look around?

Comment: They're all very strange :-).

Comment: I only hang around for the mythical Loyalty Bonus. If you've been here for long enough then you *must* get a bonus.

Comment: main personality type is obsessive compulsive downvoter (oops I am one of these, you see!)

Comment: @gnat You ain't got nothing on [some people](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/193762/fbueckert).

Comment: Unicorns and hats. Oh, and cache. Lots of cache.

Comment: @fredley all right, 337:27 looks respectable. In my defense, at Programmers I've got reasonably decent [21,814 downvotes](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/31260/gnat) (about 2/3 of which are on deleted posts)

Comment: We are free-wheeling free-hand-circle-drawing unicorn people.

Comment: @matt Accept accept accept guru guru guru horror horror horror

Answer (score 11):

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users

Comment: Delightfully laconic.

Comment: -1: Single line answers which provide no context are frowned upon almost everywhere on stack exchange.

Comment: Laconically delightful.

Comment: While this link might answer the question, link-only answers are frowned upon on stackoverflow. It's better to also summarize the contents of the link here as well. I'd recommend copying and pasting the profiles of all 95,000 or so meta users into your answer. That should give the OP a good understanding.

Comment: Is there an echo around here?

Comment: Are we in the grand canyon or something? I think there's an echo around here.

Comment: This is a nice answer but you have no sense for anthropology..... ;)